# IC-7300 internal tuner failing when before tuning I have a 1.5:1 SWR?

Tags: antenna-tuner, equipment-troubleshooting, icom-ic-7300

I have an IC-7300 and have tried it with a couple of antennas. In each case the internal tuner works sometimes, and not others.  That is not a surprise in itself, but sometimes when the untuned SWR is 1.5:1 the internal tuner still fails. I can operate at 1.5:1, but why is it failing?  E.g. in the 20m band, with an EFHW antenna which is resonant in the band.

Specifically, if I hold down "tuner" the tune light goes on and after a short couple of clicks goes off. If I try several times I get the same result.  On the other hand, on some other bands with worse SWR, it tunes fine.  That is, I hold down "tuner" and it clicks a few times and eventually stops and the tune light stays on.

The radio is new and I am still learning to use it, but I think I'm doing this right.  Any explanation, coaching or recommended troubleshooting?

Thanks.

Comment: Could it be refusing to tune because the antenna is already under 1.5:1? Can you somehow tell if it's stopping due to failure or stopping with success?

Comment: can you add some information about how you are matching your (high impedance) EFHW to the 50 ohm input on your radio?

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "fails"? That could mean more than failing to tune to a 1:1 VSWR.

Comment: How certain are you that you are 1.5:1 on 20m? I have a 7300 and it seems the worse the SWR the quicker the auto-tuner gives up and turn off the TUNE light. So if it clicks a few times, that might indicate that you aren't too far off.  Just as an experiment, I would try at several frequencies in the 20m band.

Answer (score 1):

It may be only tuning when deemed necessary. The tune light may light up only while the inductors/capacitors are actually in use. The 1.5:1 SWR might not be deemed dangerous by the algorithm inside your 7300 and the tuner might not turn on.

In other words: Your radio is smarter than you give it credit for, or it's defective.

73 DE AI7OW dit dit